# Would appreciate some help getting datadir parameter to work in Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am trying to use Bitcoin Core 0.18.1 on Linux Mint 19.2. I have previously used an older version on Win7 with no problems.

I have moved my old data directory to a new ext4 partition on an internal hdd. Bitcoin is installed on internal ssd. Everything was fine using default /home/admin1/.var/app/org.bitcoincore.bitcoin-qt/data/.

I cannot get the datadir parameter to work (-datadir=/mnt/WDRED/BitcoinData/). It keeps saying the folder does not exist. I tried deleting the default data folder and replacing it with a symlink to the actual folder on hdd but it says the same thing that the symlink folder does not exist.

Somebody might tell me ultimately I have done something stupid or I should have been able to figure it out myself but I have tried what I could from reading up and I am frustrated now. Thank you.

EDIT----

I have now solved the problem hopefully. I installed bitcoin core from within the native software manager in Linux Mint originally. This installed via flatpak. I subsequently read about flatpak and saw that it was running the application in a sandbox (from what I gather?) so I don't think it could see any path on my system that was not within that sandbox.

I uninstalled bitcoin core and reinstalled via snapd. That installation was able to obey the parameter as I expected it to so it is now verifying the existing block files and my problem (it seems atm) is solved...